# Old Github contributions not showing

Tags: git, github, github-pages

I had to add the email to my Github account to associate commits from a private repository with my accounts.

As shown on the commit history in this repo, my account is correctly mapped, however, I still don't see contributions on my personal Github page. Is there an available solution to update it?

[image: Commits]

[image: Contributions graph]

Searched for an answer, added email associated to commits in the Github settings page.

EDIT:

- [profile](https://github.com/qwe2tz)
- [repo](https://github.com/qwe2tz)